# Is there a Reshape technique to fix the array size?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, lstm

My problem here that I want to make the number of input channels in python equals to dimension of filters

here some code of what i had tried

i already tried to reshape but it gives me the same error .. and because I am new in python I couldn't understand how to fix my error My model is about combining cnn with lstm layer and i have 2892 training images and 1896 testing images with total 4788 images each image with size 128*128

```
cnn_model = Sequential()

cnn_model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(128,128,3),data_format='channels_last'))
print (cnn_model.output_shape)
cnn_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
print (cnn_model.output_shape)
cnn_model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu',data_format='channels_last'))
print (cnn_model.output_shape)
cnn_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
print (cnn_model.output_shape)

cnn_model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu',data_format='channels_last'))
print (cnn_model.output_shape)
cnn_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
print (cnn_model.output_shape)

cnn_model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu',data_format='channels_last'))
print (cnn_model.output_shape)
cnn_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
print ("MP",cnn_model.output_shape)
cnn_model.add(Flatten())
print (cnn_model.output_shape)
cnn_model.summary()
model = Sequential()
model.add(cnn_model)
print (model.output_shape)
model.add(Reshape((4608,1)))
model.add(LSTM(16,return_sequences=True, dropout=0.5))
print ("LSTM",model.output_shape)

model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

X_data = np.array(X_data)
X_datatest = np.array(X_datatest)
model.add(Reshape((-1,128,128,3)))
hist=model.fit(X_data, X_data,epochs=15,batch_size=128,verbose = 2,validation_data=(X_data, X_data))
```

but it getting me the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\bdyssm\Desktop\Master\LSTMCNN2.py", line 193, in 
>       model.add(Reshape((2892,1)))   File "C:\Users\bdyssm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py",
>   line 181, in add
>       output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])   File "C:\Users\bdyssm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py",
>   line 474, in **call**
>       output_shape = self.compute_output_shape(input_shape)   File "C:\Users\bdyssm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core.py",
>   line 398, in compute_output_shape
>       input_shape[1:], self.target_shape)   File "C:\Users\bdyssm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core.py",
>   line 386, in _fix_unknown_dimension
>       raise ValueError(msg) ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged

Answer (score 0):

After you add the Dense layer, the output shape is: `(None, 4608, 1)`, so the total size is `batch_size * 4608`

But then you want to add a Reshape layer `Reshape((-1,128,128,3))` whose total size would be `batch_size * 128 * 128 * 3 = batch_size * 49152`

This is where your problem is.

Comment: So.. how to fix this issue ?

Comment: i add the reshape to make it with 4 dimensions like the input data

Comment: when i try to remove the reshape(-1,128,128,3) it gives me the following error "ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (2892, 128, 128, 3)"

Answer (score 0):

If your first dense has a shape of 60 then Reshape() must be proportional e.g. 3,20:

```
  def create_model():
    clf = Sequential()
    clf.add(Dense(60, input_dim=Input_Dim, activation='relu'))
    print('clf.output_shape1: ',clf.output_shape)  # clf.output_shape1:  (None, 60)
    clf.add(Reshape((3,20)))
    clf.add(LSTM(LSTM_out, dropout=0.5, recurrent_dropout=0.5))
```